Attempt to implement Google instruction to connect Firebase failed - "Plugin with id 'com.android.application' was already requested at line 1""
This is an ordinary Java project to Android, I just want to connect Firebase to my project.
I try to implement this instruction step-by-step
Google instuction
And currently, I have exactly what Google requires:
In top-level I have in build.gradle.kts:
plugins {   
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false   
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false  
}

In app/build.gradle.kts:
plugins {   
   id("com.android.application")   
   alias(libs.plugins.android.application)   
   id("com.google.gms.google-services")   
}   

I also placed google-service.json inside and made synchronization as Google requires
synchronisation
After I passed all the steps in Google instructions carefully my project became unworkable and broken. Error message:
Plugin with id 'com.android.application' was already requested at line 1

I'm sorry, what's going wrong?

You're getting that error because of duplicate code. In your app/build.gradle.kts file, please remove the first line:
plugins {   
   //id("com.android.application") //
   alias(libs.plugins.android.application)   
   id("com.google.gms.google-services")   
}


Thanks, found new error in this case "Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:testClasses' as task 'testClasses' not found in project ':app'."

The fact that you are getting another error, means that the initial error disappeared and this is good news :) but this sounds like a new issue that should be considered another question. As a personal guess, I think that is elated to this issue. If not, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own MCVE, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Thank @Alex  Mamo. I just expected - if I try to implement public Google instruction step-by-step, I must receive goal of that instruction, isn't it? Not a number of questions to StackOverflow, isn't it? I just click absolutely all default project in Android Studio and Java with all default setting - and what I should receive? Number of questions to StackOverflow?
